# мусор в массиве после конструктора копирования

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, char, конструктор-копирования

После операции копирования в массиве-копии находится мусор. Изначально я думал что массив-копия больше копируемого, в связи с этим там и образовываются мусорные данные из памяти, но после попытки фикса все так и остается. Может это и вовсе не конструктор копирования, а бред полнейший, такой исход тоже не исключен, в связи с тем что я новичок.
Заголовок:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyString {
private:
    char* str;
    int length;
public:
    MyString();//default constructor
    MyString(const char* str);//string constructor
    MyString(const MyString& other);//copy constructor
    ~MyString();//destructor
    void show();
};
MyString::MyString() {
    str = nullptr;
    adress = nullptr;
}
MyString::MyString(const char* str) {
    int length = strlen(str);
    this->length = length;
    this->str = new char[length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        this->str[i] = str[i];
    }
    this->str[length + 1] = '\0';
}
MyString::MyString(const MyString& other) {
    this->length = other.length;
    this->str = new char[other.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        this->str[i] = other.str[i];
        if (i = length) {
            str[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    //other.str[length] = '\0';
}
MyString::~MyString() {
    delete this->str;
}
void MyString::show() {
    cout << str << endl;;
}
#endif //MAIN
```

Сам main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
int main()
{
    MyString str("Sss");
    str.show();
    MyString str2(str);
    str2.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем потихоньку...

Что за

```
adress = nullptr;
```

Никакого `adress` у вас нет! А вот тут же занулить бы на всякий пожарный и длину не мешало бы. Или вообще использовать

```
MyString::MyString(const char* str = "") {
```

как конструктор по умолчанию.

```
this->str = new char[length + 1];
...
this->str[length + 1] = '\0';
```

Имеем выход за границы массива.

В копирующем вы выделяете недостаточно памяти:

```
this->str = new char[other.length];
```

и потом,

```
    if (i = length) {
```

Может, `==` ? И вообще, какой смысл в этом нолике? просто копируйте `length+1` символ и все... Только памяти выделите достаточное количество!

Но этот мусорный символ у вас - из-за `this->str[length + 1] = '\0';`

P.S. Не забудьте корректно написать оператор присваивания!